# What is the proper way of displaying portrait images in Jekyll + minima theme?

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I'm using [Jekyll's minima theme](https://github.com/jekyll/minima). I have a blog post with a series of images. All images are displayed in landscape mode (even the ones that should be portrait).

[image]

If I open the portrait image in new tab, the browser displays it correctly, like so:

[image]

Is there a way to make pictures display properly? Currently using:

```
![](\assets\20190227_074436.jpg)
```

I tried adding this in main.css

```
.rotate {
  -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

using this in the blog post

```
<img src="\assets\20190227_074436.jpg" class="rotate">
```

but that makes the picture overlap the pictures above and the text below. As shown below:

[image]

Is there a proper way to have pictures displayed in portrait using Jekyll + minima theme?

Cheers,